# Using ls and stat

Tags: ls, stat

I have written this script, however the output is not correct. It returns stat cannot stat no such file or directory. The file format is Living Room-20180418-0955588134.jpg

Any help will be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh

LASTFILE=$(cd /volume1/surveillance/@Snapshot && ls *.jpg  | tail -1)



# Input file

# How many seconds before file is deemed "older"
OLDTIME=3600
# Get current and file times
CURTIME=$(date +%s)
FILETIME=$(stat "$LASTFILE" -c %Y)
TIMEDIFF=$(expr $CURTIME - $FILETIME)

# Check if file older
if [ $TIMEDIFF -gt $OLDTIME ]; then

echo "No Movement Dectected in Last Hour" ;
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: You are getting filenames from a different directory than what you run `stat` in. Also [don't parse the output from `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `find` or compatible:

```
if
  ! find /volume1/surveillance/@Snapshot -name '*.jpg' -mmin -60 |
    grep -q '^'
then
  echo No movement detected in the last hour
  exit 1
fi
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
last_hour=(/volume1/surveillance/@Snapshot/*.jpg(Nmh-1))
if (($#last_hour = 0)); then
  echo No movement detected in the last hour
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because "stat" doesn't see the full path "/volume1/surveillance/@Snapshot/". It just sees the filename. So you need to modify the 
script.

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=/volume1/surveillance/@Snapshot
LASTFILE=$(cd $DIR && ls *.jpg  | tail -1)

# Input file

# How many seconds before file is deemed "older"
OLDTIME=3600
# Get current and file times
CURTIME=$(date +%s)
FILETIME=$(stat $DIR/$LASTFILE -c %Y)
TIMEDIFF=$(expr $CURTIME - $FILETIME)

# Check if file older
if [ $TIMEDIFF -gt $OLDTIME ]; then

 echo "No Movement Dectected in Last Hour" ;
 exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Why not replace the whole script with `find dir -type f -mtime +1` or something similar?

Comment: Yes. your method is the perfect one but the OP wants to get the last file. "LASTFILE=$(cd $DIR && ls *.jpg  | tail -1)"